# Why doesn't my temperature conversion calculate correctly?

Tags: java

I am trying to take my Temperature in Fahrenheit and convert it to Celsius. When I call my toCelsius() method it calculates the Temperature to 0 degrees celsius.

Here is my conversion method

```
    public Temperature toCelsius()
    {
    Temperature answer = new Temperature();
    switch(tempType)
    {
    case 'C':
        answer =  new Temperature(this.temp,'C');
        return answer;
    case 'F':
        answer =  new Temperature(((this.temp-32)*(5/9)),'C');
        return answer;

    case 'K':
        answer =  new Temperature((this.temp-241.15),'C');
        return answer;

    default:
        System.out.println("ERROR!");
        break;

    }
    return answer;
    }
```

Here is my demo

```
    public class TempDemo {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Temperature temp1 = new Temperature(122, 'F');
            System.out.println(temp1.toCelsius());
      }

    }
```

Comment: Division with integers does not produce a decimal number I think. `5/9` equals to `0`. I think you have to use `double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`5` and `9` are `int` literals, so dividing them will be done using [integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers) - i.e., it will take only the whole part of the division. Since 5 is smaller than 9, this will result in `0`, and thus so would the entire multiplication.

Instead, you should use `double` literals:

```
answer =  new Temperature(((this.temp-32)*(5.0/9.0)), 'C');
```

Comment: If you want to keep it an `int` value you could do `(this.temp - 32) * 5 / 9` and get a close answer. +1